# How to take command argument in Go?

Tags: go, command-line-arguments

I just start to learn Go, and I wrote a prime test program using the `ProbablyPrime` library.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "math"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func prime_test(n int64, certainty int)(bool,float64){
    var probobility float64
    i := big.NewInt(n)
    isPrime := i.ProbablyPrime(certainty)
    probobility = 1 - 1/math.Pow(4,10)
    return isPrime, probobility
}

func why_not_prime(n int64)(int64){
    var i int64 
    for  i=2 ; i<n/2; i++ {
        if n%i == 0 {return i}
    }
    return i
}


func main() {
    var n int64
    var certainty int
    var isPrime bool
    var probobility float64 

    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
    n,_ = strconv.ParseInt(os.Args[1],64,64)
    certainty,_ = strconv.Atoi(os.Args[2])
    }

    isPrime, probobility = prime_test(n,certainty)
    if isPrime {
        fmt.Printf("%d is probably %0.8f%% a prime.", n, probobility*100)
    } else {
        var i int64
        i = why_not_prime(n)
        fmt.Printf("%d is a composite because it can be divided by %d", n, i)
    }
}
```

The code could be successfully compiled. When I run it, it always return `0 is a composite because it can be divided by 2`.

I guess there's something wrong with the command line argument parsing. How to fix it?

Comment: My guess is that `len(os.Args)` is not greater than one, and that that's why `n` is not being set to anything but `0`.  I'd insert a print statement in the `if` statement to check whether or not this is the case.

Comment: @SelectricSimian Thank you. I put `fmt.Println("More than 1 arguments")` in the `if` statement, run it with `./prime.exe 39393993 10` and I got `More than 1 arguments
0 is a composite because it can be divided by 2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
n,_ = strconv.ParseInt(os.Args[1],64,64)
```

The documentation of [`ParseInt(s string, base int, bitSize int) (i int64, err error)`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt) states:

> ParseInt interprets a string s in the given base (2 to 36) and returns the corresponding value i.

The base can be **`36`** at the most and you pass `64`. In this case an error will be returned (which you discard by using the blank identifier `_`), and `n` will have the zero value which is `0` hence you see the output as

> **0** is a composite because it can be divided by 2

**Solution:**

Change the line in question to this:

```
n, _ = strconv.ParseInt(os.Args[1], 10, 64)
```

and it should work. Also you should not discard errors because you will run into cases like this. Instead handle them properly like this:

```
var err error
n, err = strconv.ParseInt(os.Args[1], 10, 64)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

**Note:**

Also note that the first argument (`os.Args[0]` is the name of the executable), and since you expect and work with 2 extra arguments, you should check if the length of `os.Args` is greater than 2 not 1:

```
if len(os.Args) > 2 {
    // os.Args[1] and os.Args[2] is valid
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! After I add `n, err :...`, I got this error: `prog.go:36: n declared and not used` line 36 is the line `n, err: ...` If I remove this line and use `n,_ = ...` instead, the program runs correctly. So there's something wrong with the err handling.

Comment: @Nick That is because the `:=` assigns the result to new variables and you declared your `n` variable outside of the containing `if` block (so the one created inside the `if` block is not used, only the "outer" one). You can solve this by also declaring the `err` (either outside or inside the `if` block) and just use simple assignment: `n, err = ...`.

Comment: I added `var err error` before `n, err = ...`, it works. Thank you very much!